# Unable to Upgrade PHP 7.1 to PHP 7.2 in Windows

Tags: php, xampp

I am unable to upgrade from PHP 7.1 to PHP 7.2.

I download this below.
https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.2-ts-VC15-x64

I rename my old PHP folder into php-older and make a new folder of PHP in XAMPP directory. I pasted the downloaded zip & extract it there. Whenever I re run Apache I found the error below.

> phpMyAdmin - Error The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your
>   PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information.

```
[Wed Jun 03 17:42:39.321532 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9952:tid 536] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 03 17:42:39.476157 2020] [core:warn] [pid 9952:tid 536] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Jun 03 17:42:39.595071 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9952:tid 536] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 03 17:42:39.601067 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9952:tid 536] AH00455: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2r PHP/7.2.31 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 03 17:42:39.601067 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9952:tid 536] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Mar 31 2019 13:05:21
[Wed Jun 03 17:42:39.601067 2020] [core:notice] [pid 9952:tid 536] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Jun 03 17:42:39.605066 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9952:tid 536] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 16256
[Wed Jun 03 17:42:40.757201 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 16256:tid 516] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 03 17:42:41.038429 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 16256:tid 516] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jun 03 17:42:41.054057 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16256:tid 516] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Do you have the mysqli extension enabled?

Comment: Upgrade? Deinstall xampp, reinstall xampp with 7.2?

Comment: You need to choose: XAMPP or official binaries. What you're doing is like trying to install PowerPoint inside `C:\Program Files\LibreOffice`.

Comment: Whenever i try to install composer, it don't install all dependencies.For somehow, xamp is running.